# Linq GroupBy - how to specify the grouping key at runtime?

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

is there a good way to do a Linq `GroupBy` where the grouping key is determined at runtime? e.g. I want the grouping key to be built from a user-selected list of fields - can you do this? I know I can do it easily if I convert everything to a table of strings, but I was wondering if there was an elegant or clever way to accomplish this otherwise.

```
class Item
{
    public int A, B;
    public DateTime D;
    public double X, Y, Z;
}
```

I have a `List<Item>` called `data`. I want to do things like retrieve the sum of `X` grouped by `A`, or the sums of `X`, `Y`, and `Z`, grouped by `A` and `B`. but what fields go into the grouping should be able to be specified at runtime in some way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx) code and use the extension from it that allows you to specify the keySelector with a string.

```
var query = db.Foo.GroupBy( "{0}", "GroupedProperty", groupKey );
```

You might also want to consider adding your own extension if you want to get back the entire object grouped by the key.

```
public static IQueryable GroupByComplete( this IQueryable source, string keySelector, params object[] values )
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException( "source" );
    if (keySelector == null) throw new ArgumentNullException( "keySelector" );
    LambdaExpression keyLambda = DynamicExpression.ParseLambda( source.ElementType, null, keySelector, values );
    return source.Provider.CreateQuery(
        Expression.Call(
            typeof( Queryable ), "GroupBy",
            new Type[] { source.ElementType, keyLambda.Body.Type },
            source.Expression, Expression.Quote( keyLambda ) ) );
}
```

Comment: that looks like what I want. looking at the source code, I guess it's more complex than I imagined, good thing I didn't spend much time trying to write it myself :)

Answer (score 8):

All you need is to construct a Func<Item, TKey>  at run-time:

```
var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Item), "item");
var body = Expression.Property(arg, "D");
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Item, DateTime>>(body, arg);
var keySelector = lambda.Compile();
```

Usage:

```
var result = source.GroupBy(keySelector);
```

It gets slightly (but not much) more difficult if you don't know the type of the property at compile-time.

Comment: was trying to do that but couldn't figure out the syntax, thanks for the example.

Comment: This just helped me - thanks.  What are your options if you don't know the return type of the Func<> at compile time?

Comment: @NathanRatcliff Do you know the answer for this question already ?