# Linq - Dynamic GroupBy with IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, ienumerable

I have a collection that is `IEnumerable<Transaction>`.  Transaction has several properties such as TransactionId (Int64), PaymentMethod(string) and TransactionDate(DateTime)

I'd like to be able to accomplish this `transactions.GroupBy(x => x.PaymentMethod)` dynamically at run time based on whatever grouping field the user has decided to use.

I found most of the answer I'm looking for in dtb's answer here [Linq GroupBy - how to specify the grouping key at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2914656/linq-groupby-how-to-specify-the-grouping-key-at-runtime)

This works well:

```
        var arg = Expression.Parameter( typeof( Transaction ), "transaction" );
        var body = Expression.Property( arg, "PaymentMethod" );
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Transaction, string>>( body, arg );
        var keySelector = lambda.Compile();

        var groups = transactions.GroupBy( keySelector );
```

Except that I don't know the type of the return type of the Func in `Expression.Lambda<Func<Transaction, string>>`.  It's string in this example, but it might be Int64, decimal, DateTime, etc.  I can't use Object as the return type because I might have value types.

I've been reading lots of SO posts and most of them seem to apply to IQueryable and LinqToSQL.

Using the Expression class seems like a good way to accomplish this, but is there a way to do it when I don't know either the name or datatype of my group parameter at compile time?

I appreciate any nudge in the right direction.

Edit:

Using Polity's solution below, I created an extension method that does what I've been trying to do:

```
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<object, T>> GroupBy<T>( this IEnumerable<T> items, string groupByProperty )
    {

        var arg = Expression.Parameter( typeof(T), "item" );
        var body = Expression.Convert( Expression.Property( arg, groupByProperty ), typeof( object ) );
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>( body, arg );
        var keySelector = lambda.Compile();

        var groups = items.GroupBy( keySelector );
        return groups;
    }
```

Thanks to Polity and everyone who answered!

Comment: can you put these codes into a generic method and set the return type as the type of the generic argument?

Comment: If I understand your question, I don't think so.  Pretty much all I'll have is the string name of the property the users have selected as a group key.  I figured I'd have to use some reflection to get the type.

Comment: One of the guys I work with suggested creating a switch statement based on the type of the grouping property, adding a case for all of the value types and having default use object as it's type.  That would work, but I think I'd need a shower after coding it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following up on the answer of ojlovecd.

According to the one asking he needs functionality at runtime. Generics and Runtime arent the easiest mix. That is no problem though since you can just threat the return value as an object which makes the non-generic variant of the method provided by ojlovecd something like:

```
static IEnumerable<IGrouping<object,Transaction>> GroupBy(string propName) 
{ 
    List<Transaction> transactions = new List<Transaction>  
    { 
        new Transaction{ PaymentMethod="AA", SomeDateTime=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), SomeDecimal=1.2M, SomeInt64=1000}, 
        new Transaction{ PaymentMethod="BB", SomeDateTime=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2), SomeDecimal=3.4M, SomeInt64=2000}, 
        new Transaction{ PaymentMethod="AA", SomeDateTime=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), SomeDecimal=3.4M, SomeInt64=3000}, 
        new Transaction{ PaymentMethod="CC", SomeDateTime=DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), SomeDecimal=5.6M, SomeInt64=1000}, 
    }; 
    var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Transaction), "transaction"); 
    var body = Expression.Convert(Expression.Property(arg, propName), typeof(object)); 
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Transaction, object>>(body, arg); 
    var keySelector = lambda.Compile(); 

    var groups = transactions.GroupBy(keySelector); 
    return groups; 
}
```

Comment: I tried this earlier.  It works great when the grouping value is a reference type, but you can't use it for value types (like Int64).  You get this:  System.ArgumentException: Expression of type 'System.Int64' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'

Comment: @Nathan Ratcliff - I edited the code somewhat to include a Cast from the proprety to an object. This isn't perfect though since i doubt many systems will understand this. EF for one doesnt understand casts, but it works for linq to objects

Comment: Thank you, this works for me.  I'm still learning my way around the Expression stuff.

Answer (score 1):

the following codes are what I mean, hoping they are helpful:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    var query = GroupBy<string>("PaymentMethod");
    foreach (var group in query)
        Console.WriteLine(group.Key + "," + group.Count());
    var query2 = GroupBy<long>("SomeInt64");
    foreach (var group in query2)
        Console.WriteLine(group.Key + "," + group.Count());
}

static IEnumerable<IGrouping<T,Transaction>> GroupBy<T>(string propName)
{
    List<Transaction> transactions = new List<Transaction> 
    {
        new Transaction{ PaymentMethod="AA", SomeDateTime=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), SomeDecimal=1.2M, SomeInt64=1000},
        new Transaction{ PaymentMethod="BB", SomeDateTime=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2), SomeDecimal=3.4M, SomeInt64=2000},
        new Transaction{ PaymentMethod="AA", SomeDateTime=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1), SomeDecimal=3.4M, SomeInt64=3000},
        new Transaction{ PaymentMethod="CC", SomeDateTime=DateTime.Now.AddDays(2), SomeDecimal=5.6M, SomeInt64=1000},
    };
    var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Transaction), "transaction");
    var body = Expression.Property(arg, propName);
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Transaction, T>>(body, arg);
    var keySelector = lambda.Compile();

    var groups = transactions.GroupBy(keySelector);
    return groups;
}

    class Transaction
    {
        public string PaymentMethod { get; set; }
        public Int64 SomeInt64 { get; set; }
        public decimal SomeDecimal { get; set; }
        public DateTime SomeDateTime { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the types at compile time.  All I'll have is the property name, I'll have to determine the type at run time.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to construct the delegate type and use `Expression.Call()` and finally execute the `GroupBy` using `DynamicInvoke()` if you do not know the target type at compile time - this works for me:

```
var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Transaction), "transaction");
var body = Expression.Property(arg, "PaymentMethod");

var delegateType = typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(Transaction), body.Type);
var lambda = Expression.Lambda(delegateType, body, arg);
var source = Expression.Parameter(typeof(IEnumerable<Transaction>), "source");
var groupByExpression = Expression.Call(typeof(Enumerable), "GroupBy", 
                                        new Type[] { typeof(Transaction), body.Type }, 
                                        source, lambda);
var groupByLambda = Expression.Lambda(groupByExpression, source).Compile();

var groups = groupByLambda.DynamicInvoke(transactions);
```

Since at this point you cannot use any other Linq extension methods without converting them to expressions as well (at least as far as I understand it) the benefit is doubtful, so I personally probably would go with one of the other options presented.

Comment: I upvoted anyway - it's what I thought I wanted to do, but like you point out, you can't use groups unless you know types.  Thanks for the answer.