# LINQ group by dynamic

Tags: c#, linq, dynamic, group-by, dynamic-linq

I am trying to make a dynamic grouping for LINQ and I am just not getting the syntax correct.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Here is my static LINQ code;

```
var query =
    from x in myCollection
    group x by x.Field1 into g
    select new myClass
    {
            /// <summary>
            /// Group logic removed
            /// </summary>
    };
```

thanks

edit:
I did see some examples but it seems I am not smart enough to figure it.  Also I just realized that I never stated `myCollection` is an ObservableCollection
This is what I have tried to make the above query into;

```
var group = myCollection.GroupBy(
"new(it[\"Field1\"] as Field1,it[\"Field2\"]as Field2)", "it"
)
.Select(x =>
new myClass {
    Net = x.Sum(y => y.Net),
    Field1 = x.First().Field1,
    Field2 = x.First().Field2,
} );
```

This returns an error of;

```
The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.GroupBy<TSource,TKey>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,TKey>, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer<TKey>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

Comment: Are all of the potential fields that you're grouping on of the same type?

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you want to do?

Comment: You're not the first one... http://stackoverflow.com/q/10797997/861716, and many more. Did you try any of these solutions?

Comment: please read edit above

Comment: Try `it.Field1"` etc.

Comment: `"new(it.Field1, it.Field2", "it"` returns the same error